# No display manager after Debian 12 installation on Hyper-V

Tags: debian, lightdm, hyper-v

I installed (graphical installation, selecting xfce) [Debian 12](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-12.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso) on Hyper-V Gen1 VM within Windows 10. When reboot Debian no login screen appears. What cause the problem that lightdm does not start? Same issue if I run  Debian 12 live iso with different DEs. Go to text terminal `alt+f1` and collect some information:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/sbin/lightdm

$ systemctl status lightdm.service
× lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-07-13 23:48:57 CEST; 22min ago
   Duration: 34ms
       Docs: man:lightdm(1)
   Main PID: 612 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 36ms

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.

$ sudo lightdm --test-mode --debug
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.26.0, UID=0 PID=6878
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using cross-namespace EXTERNAL authentication (this will deadlock if server is GDBus < 2.73.3)
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.01s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 has property CanMultiSession=no
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching process 6884: /usr/bin/X :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] WARNING: Could not enumerate user data directory /var/lib/lightdm/data: Error opening directory '/var/lib/lightdm/data': No such file or directory
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to 
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Process 6884 exited with return value 1
[+0.07s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.07s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping; greeter display server failed to start
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1


$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     6.524] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.7
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     6.524] Current Operating System: Linux aristarchos 6.1.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.37-1 (2023-07-03) x86_64
[     6.524] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.1.0-10-amd64 root=UUID=60c98bf2-7c27-4ea9-bada-f3ae1e1e642f ro quiet
[     6.524] xorg-server 2:21.1.7-3 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[     6.524] Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
[     6.524]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     6.524] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     6.524] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Jul 13 23:48:56 2023
[     6.525] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     6.525] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     6.525] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     6.525] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     6.525] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     6.525] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     6.525] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     6.525] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     6.525] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     6.525] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[     6.525] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     6.525] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     6.525]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     6.525] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     6.525] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     6.525] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     6.525] (II) Loader magic: 0x55f4a49d2f00
[     6.525] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     6.525]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     6.525]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[     6.525]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[     6.525]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     6.526] (++) using VT number 7

[     6.526] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     6.527] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     6.527] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/device:07/VMBUS:01/5620e0c7-8062-4dce-aeb7-520c7ef76171/drm/card0
[     6.531] (--) PCI:*(0@0:8:0) 1414:5353:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xf8000000/67108864, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     6.531] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     6.532] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     6.533] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.533]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.533]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     6.533] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[     6.533] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[     6.533] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[     6.533] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     6.533] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     6.533] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     6.533] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.533]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 1.21.1
[     6.533]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     6.533]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[     6.533] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     6.533] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     6.533] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.533]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[     6.533]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     6.533]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[     6.533] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     6.533] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     6.533] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.533]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[     6.533]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     6.533]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[     6.533] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     6.534] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     6.534] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     6.534] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     6.535] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[     6.535] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     6.535] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     6.535] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     6.535] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.535]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 0.0.2
[     6.535]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[     6.535] (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
[     6.535] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     6.535] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     6.535] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     6.535] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     6.535] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.535]    compiled for 1.21.1.7, module version = 0.0.2
[     6.535]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[     6.535] (II) FBDEV(3): using default device
[     6.535] vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
[     6.536] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[     6.536] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     6.536] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     6.536] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     6.536] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     6.536] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     6.536] (EE) Screen 2 deleted because of no matching config section.
[     6.536] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     6.536] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[     6.536] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[     6.536] (EE) 
[     6.536] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     6.536] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     6.536] (EE) 
[     6.544] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I also found [this](https://blog.jsobczak.com/2019/12/07/manjaro-light-display-manager-failed-to-start-on-hyper-v-gen2-vm/) post, that describes same problem (but on Hyper-V Gen2 insted of Gen1) and suggest to install `xf86-video-fbdev`. I reinstalled the equivalent package for Debian and `lightdm` as well:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

If I'm not wrong it is called a greeter, the GUI that prompts the user for credentials. So I checked lightdm config:

```
$ sudo lightdm --show-config
[sudo] password for user: 
   [Seat:*]
A  greeter-session=lightdm-greeter
A  greeter-hide-users=true
A  session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession

   [LightDM]
B  logind-check-graphical=false

Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_debian.conf
B  /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Is `lightdm-greeter` a correct greeter? I ask because if I search for greeter I found `lightdm-gtk-greeter`, `lightdm-deepin-greeter`, `lightdm-pantheon-greeter`, `lightdm-webkit2-greeter` , etc. but no `lightdm-greeter`.

Comment: Searching for the first error in that log like so `Unable to find a valid framebuffer device hyper-v debian` I found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=271255) - there's other results in the search that may also be helpful - sometimes, you just have to know what to search for

Comment: @JaromandaX, thx for the link, unfortunately the solution there, to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-fbdev.conf` with corresponding content does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you want me to post every link I found so you can take 8 hours to try? There's about 359,000 links ... so, it could take 327 years at this rate if the the last result is the one that helps you. Unfortunately, I have plans for most of that time. In case you're wondering, my plans are to be pushing up daisies

Comment: So on boot, you get dropped into the terminal? I would try starting the desktop environment from the terminal and see if that works (i.e. run `startx /usr/bin/xxx` , where xxx is the executable for your DE). You could also try running a different display manager (e.g. `sddm`). You need to narrow down whether the issue is with the DM or X11.

Comment: Your log contains this: `Error opening directory '/var/lib/lightdm/data': No such file or directory`.  That's the important part.  Try `sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm` to re-configure the package.  Hopefully that will trigger something in `postinst` to create that directory.  A more hacky way could be to make that directory yourself, but that might just lead you into the next problem.